# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade (Flutter)

Tags: windows, flutter

error：

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> G:\FlutterProject\flutter_app_audanika\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:53: AAPT: error: 'drawable/launch_background' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference.

Comment: my AndroidManifest.xml line:53<meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="drawable/launch_background" />
</manifest>

Comment: `meta-data` must be into `<aplication><activity><meta-data ... /> </aplication></activity>`, do you have there?